# How to configure ILogger in AzureFunction app with BlobTrigger?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

My Code :

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
namespace sampleapplication
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([BlobTrigger("testcontainer/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
        }
    }
}
```

While Running the App ,

```
[30-01-2019 10:56:19] Run: 
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1.Run'.
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind parameter 'log' to type ILogger.
 Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. If you're using binding extensions (e.g. ServiceBus, Timers, etc.)
 make sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. config.UseServiceBus(), config.UseTimers(), etc.).
```

TraceWritter is the Default but unit test case for trace writer is unable to do.
so i searched many sites where They prefered Ilogger.

How to initialize Ilogger in Azure Function App ?

Comment: ILogger was expected to be supported out of the box in V2 environment. Check your environment version. As I do not have first hand experience working on V2 so not very sure on this.. Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/ILogger

Comment: What version of the Azure Functions Runtime are you using - 1.x or 2.x?

Comment: To add another question -- what version of Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions are you referencing in your project? I wonder if there's a version mismatch somehow...

Answer (score 1):

Create your function using runtime version 2.x you will get Ilogger as default. see the screenshot below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jBDs.png)